# Cannot find data in Prometheus with InfluxDB remote write/read api

Tags: influxdb, prometheus, remotestorage

InfluxDB announced Prometheus remote write/read api in ver1.4.

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.4/supported_protocols/prometheus/ https://www.influxdata.com/blog/influxdb-now-supports-prometheus-remote-read-write-natively/

I have deployed a new InfluxDB, created a user called "paul" with password 'foo', created a database called "prometheus" and filled with sample data:

[image]

Then, I modified the config yml of Prometheus (I found the '*' in influx doc example should be replaced by '-')

[image]

I believe Prometheus and InfluxDB are communicating:

[image]

However, I cannot find the sample measurement I inserted in InfluxDB.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/92oUR.jpg]

I am sure I must miss something simple.... Did I do any silly mistakes? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found that the metrics were all put into a single measurement called '_' within the INfluxDB database that we chose (called "metrics", in our case) with the field being 'f64' (float64, I assume). The Prometheus measurement name was attached as a label: '**name**'. So, in my experience, the InfluxDB query for your measurement above might be something like:

```
select "f64" from "prometheus"."_" where "__name__" = "prometheus_target_interval_length_seconds_count"
```