# Prometheus remote read from InfluxDB not returning any data

Tags: prometheus, influxdb

I've already found two questions with the same problem as me:

1. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52882413/prometheus-remote-read-influxdb)
2. [And this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48221953/cannot-find-data-in-prometheus-with-influxdb-remote-write-read-api)

In the first one the answer is about the mapping from a prometheus metric to an influxdb measurement, which doesn't help me much, and the second one is a completely outdated solution. So here is my problem:

I have a prometheus instance with remote read configured to an InfluxDB instance. If I run this query in InfluxDB:

```
SELECT "value" FROM "responseTime" WHERE ("ms" = 'ms-address') AND time >= 1604381750000ms and time <= 1604383558000ms
```

I get data:

```
Time            responseTime
1604381751000   187
1604381811000   295
...
```

But if I run the following PromQL query:

```
responseTime{ms="ms-address"}
```

With time interval:

```
start=1604381745&end=1604383545&step=15
```

I get no data. But the request is arriving to influxdb and returns 200 OK.

```
"POST /api/v1/prom/read?db=ms_metrics&p=%5BREDACTED%5D&u=%5BREDACTED%5D HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-" "Prometheus/2.22.0" 566cbba3-1de5-11eb-83e3-9e23496fb87c 152
```

In the prometheus remote read configuration I have the `read_recent` parameter set to `true`.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: Probably it would be better switching to other remote storage solution for Prometheus that can be queried directly with PromQL without the need in setting up remote_read in Prometheus? Take a look at m3db, [victoriametrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) or cortex. BTW, VictoriaMetrics [supports data ingestion with Influx line protocol](https://victoriametrics.github.io/#how-to-send-data-from-influxdb-compatible-agents-such-as-telegraf).

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation @valyala! The thing is that I need to use it as data source for Spinnaker automated canary analysis. Either way, I'll explore the victoriametrics option with spinnaker to see if it can work. Thanks! :)